# Go to the main browser window from an embedded IFRAME inside an embedded IFRAME inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

Supposing that a Web app has an IFRAME which hosts another IFRAME which hosts another IFRAME and so on. They could be any levels deep.

All the IFRAMEs host content from the same domain.

On the client side, using javascript/jQuery, I want to get to the main browser window and then do something to it.

Here's what I am doing:

```
function findRoot()
{
  for(var _parent = window; _parent.parent != null; _parent = _parent.parent);

  return _parent;
}
```

But it goes into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `top` notation to get to the top window.

e.g.

```
top.myFunction();
```

will call `myFunction` of the top window from inside of any Iframe level

Comment: w00t! Green checkie ta ya in 7 minutes! :-)